# Microsoft Excel combining amounts

Tags: microsoft-excel

so I'm stuck with amounts of items for 3 years and my manager wants me to have a new sheet showing the total of them but I have no idea how to do that can anyone help me please really appreciated

( samples below )

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Mohamed, it's difficult to help when you don't specify what you do or don't know. Do you know anything about using formulas at all? What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to use the `SUMIF` formula.

In `B2` you put:

```
=SUMIF(Totals!$A:$D,$A2,Totals!B:B)
```

Then use the [fill handle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fill-a-formula-down-into-adjacent-cells-041edfe2-05bc-40e6-b933-ef48c3f308c6) to drag down to all the `B` rows, and after that drag the fill handle to the right on columns `C` and `D` for all years.

[image]

The result is:
[image]

Here is the view of all cells with the formulas used:
[image]

Comment: You are AZAMING thank you so much